# randomly change values in two dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to python and i'm trying to create an array (without using numpy)  and then have some values randomly replaced. The array is created using this code:

```
array = []

for row in range(6):  
    array.append([])      
    for column in range(6):  
        array[row].append('0')

def display(array):
    for row in array:
        print("  ".join(row))

display(array)
```

This code outputs:

```
0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0
```

How can I randomly select an element in this list and replace it with a 1 along with the digits above/below and next to it like so:

```
0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  0  0  0
0  1  1  1  0  0
0  0  1  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) you can check how to use lists. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html#random.randint) you can check how to get a random number... and about the 1's along the selected element, try to find a connection between the *n* element indices and its neighbours indices.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a logic to check for edge cases, or you can use exceptions as follows:

```
def node_and_neighbours(array, r, c, v):
    elements = [(r - 1, c), (r, c - 1), (r,c), (r, c + 1), (r + 1, c)]
    for (i, j) in elements:
        try:
            array[i][j] = v
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Then you can randomly select row/col indices and set its neighbours' and its own value as '1' by calling the above function.

```
import random
r = random.randint(0, len(array) - 1)
c = random.randint(0, len(array[r]) - 1)
node_and_neighbours(array, r, c, '1')
display(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

for randomly generating a number just use

```
from random import randrange
x=randrange(0,6)
print(x)
```

this will give you a random number.
and as for the changing of number around that number just use the above number and increment and decrement that number to get the index of the number around it.